# How split text with parenthesis into words using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

Here is a text with English words, CJK characters and fullwidth parenthesis(`\uff08` and `\uff09`):

`这是（一段测试）文字（start开始end）的结果`

I want to split the text into words, for CJK characters, one charcater is a word. The special point is that I also want the fullwidth left parenthesis `\uff08` combines with the word after it, and the fullwidth right parenthesis `\uff09` combines with the word before it.

The expected result will be:

```
这
是
（一
段
测
试）
文
字
（start
开
始
end）
的
结
果
```

Currently, I use `new Regex(@"(\s+)|([\u0000-\u001F\u0021-\u007F]+)|([^\u0000-\u007F])");` to split the text, but fullwidth parentheses didn't combine with the word before/after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add those special cases:

```
(\uff08(?:[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0021-\u007f]+))
```

and

```
((?:[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0021-\u007f]+)\uff09)
```

to your regex, giving you a complete regex of:

```
(\s+)|(\uff08(?:[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0021-\u007f]+))|((?:[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0021-\u007f]+)\uff09)|([\u0000-\u001F\u0021-\u007F]+)|([^\u0000-\u007F])
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/X7omDG/2)

Note they need to be added to the regex prior to the part of the regex that could match the word on its own, otherwise that match will take precedence.